# Isolated Singular Points

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, singularity

I would like to check and see if my reasoning for this question is correct:

Find the singular points of the function, and classify them if they are isolated singular points. Also, evaluate if $\infty$ is an isolated singular point.

1. $\cot \frac{1}{z}$

My reasoning for this question is similar to that found in this link below:

[Find and classify singular points of $\cot\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760084/find-and-classify-singular-points-of-cot-left-frac1z-right)

2. $e^{-z} \cos \frac{1}{z}$

$z = 0$ IS an isolated singular point this time, because $e^{-z}$ is entire, making the function analytic everywhere else. This is the only statement I'd like to check.

3. $e^{\cot(\frac{1}{z})}$
4. $\cot \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{z}$

Would we apply the same reasoning as that found in the link I posted above? That is, since $z = 0$ is not an isolated singular point of $\cot \frac{1}{z}$, the same is true the functions above?

5. $\sin{(\frac{1}{\cos {\frac{1}{z}}})}$

Not sure where to start with this one, other than perhaps identifying that $\cos \frac{1}{z}$ has multiple zeroes, making our function non-analytic in multiple points. Therefore, since the function is non-analytic for several points for all neighborhoods around $z = 0$, this is also a non-isolated singular point.

Please let me know if my logic is right, or if there's something else that needs to be addressed. Thank you!

Comment: $\sin(1/z)$ has a sequence of zeros converging to $0$, hence $\frac{1}{\sin(1/z)}$ has a sequence of poles converging to $0$, hence $z=0$ is not an isolated singularity of $\cot(1/z) = \frac{\cos(1/z)}{\sin(1/z)}$. the reasoning should be the same for the other functions.

Comment: This is what was explained in the link I posted above. Why/how does this work for the last function in this question?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\cos(1/z)}$ has a sequence of poles converging to $z=0$, and $\sin( \frac{1}{z-a})$ has an (essential) singularity at $z=a$, hence $\sin(\frac{1}{\cos(1/z)})$ has a sequence of essential singularities converging to $z=0$

Comment: Are these isolated singularities though? Sounds like if you take a neighborhood around any of these singularities, you'll always contain another. This violates the definition of isolated singularity, because for every neighborhood of an isolated singularity, every other point should be analytic.

Comment: $1 / \cos(1/z)$ has a sequence of (isolated) poles $a_n$ such that $|a_n| \to 0$, around all these $a_n$ : $\frac{1}{\cos(1/z)} = \frac{c_n}{z - a_n} + h_n(z)$ with $h_n(z)$ holomoporphic around $z=a$. you also know that $\sin(\frac{c_n}{z-a_n})$ has an isolated singularity at $z= a_n$, hence $\sin(\frac{1}{\cos(1/z)})$ too

Comment: the much more complicated case would be $\sin(\ln(\cos(1/z)))$, can you do thisone ?